# I am unable to print page on mvc5

Tags: printing

I created an MVC 5 web application using bootstrap 3.0.

I am almost done with my application but never realized that I can't print any page. The Print Preview shows blank and when i printed i get a blank page.

I never had this happen to me. What can be causing this?

Thank you in advance.

Ceci

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the media directives in your stylesheets or on your actual style tags/links. If you don't have one that is for print, your content may just be hidden. Check out https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ and http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/style/, respectively.

Simplest thing might be to add `media='all'` to your style links and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response. As it turns out, it had nothing to do with the CSS.

A closing div   was missing on the _Layout.cshml file. It works now.

Thanks again.